# Unable to get UUID and Model ionic.Platform / $cordovaDevice both

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-v1

I want to get uuid and model using ionic Platform plugin. This code

```
var deviceInfo = ionic.Platform.device();
```

is not working for me, it is returning an empty array. How can I get data in this `deviceInfo` so that I can get uuid by `deviceInfo.uuid` and model `deviceInfo.model`.

I have also tried to use `$cordovaDevice.getDevice()` but this is giving error

```
ReferenceError: device is not defined
at Object.getDevice (ng-cordova.js:1956)
```

this is the code I am using

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice(); //error here
        alert(device);
        $scope.model = device.model;
        alert(model);
        $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
        alert(uuid);
});
```

I have also installed `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device` and included `$ionicPlatform` and `$cordovaDevice` in controller parameters.

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using?

Comment: I am using ionic 1

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device#cordova-plugin-device) the plugin _defines a global device object_. So something like `$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $scope.model = device.model;
        $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
});` should work...

Comment: Just do not override the global device object, but instead access it directly...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device#cordova-plugin-device):

> This plugin defines a global `device` object, which describes the device's hardware and software. Although the object is in the global scope, it is not available until after the `deviceready` event.

So the following should work for you:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // The global device object holds the information you're looking for
        // Do not override it
        $scope.model = device.model;
        alert(device.model);
        $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
        alert(device.uuid);
});
```

Anyway make sure you're testing on a real device or emulator which is supported by this plugin.

Comment: device is not defined again

Comment: What device are you testing on?